# Text input for InteractiveMarker

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it currently possible to set up a text input for an interactive marker? Specifically in order to change the label that sits above the interactive marker. I see that it's possible to have a right click menu that works well in `rviz`, so when an entry is selected such as '**Rename**, it would be something similar to the **[Rename View](https://imgur.com/ajFv5QU)** dialog.

I am currently using ROS Kinetic, but this is a general question for any distro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319628/text-input-for-interactivemarker/) by [r0gi](https://answers.ros.org/users/40626/r0gi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this is currently not supported (or at least not by the 'standard' implementation of `interactive_markers`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0